# How to upgrade from Doctrine 1.1.4 to Doctrine 1.2.3 in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-1.2

I am trying to upgrade Doctrine in my Zend application. I changed the line in my bootstrap file to point to Doctrine 1.2.3

```
    // Autoload Doctrine ORM
    require_once(LIBRARY_PATH.'/Doctrine-1.2.3/Doctrine.php');
    spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));
```

But I get an error when accessing the application in the browser;

*Fatal error: Class 'BaseUser' not found in C:\xampplite\htdocs\SECGearbox\application\models\User.php on line 14*.

Seems like the models can't be found.

I'm not quite sure where to proceed from here.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to autoload models in Doctrine 1.2 the following line has to be added:

```
spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine_Core', 'modelsAutoload'));
```

This line is added after the two lines I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use the [ZFDoctrine](https://github.com/beberlei/zf-doctrine) integration libraries from [beberlei](https://github.com/beberlei) for my Zend Framework 1x and Doctrine 1.2 projects.  They provide nice integration between the two and make it easy to use the Zend_Tool command line for Doctrine tasks.